# Add or subtract days to date field using the field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator

I am using ArcGIS 10.1

I'm not a programmer

I want to use the field calculator to add 4 days to the current date if the status is "delivery"

or

subtract 5 days if its status is "order"

this result need to have in the field of "New Date"

[image: Example table]

current date  13/11/2014

If the status is "delivery" is new date 16/11/2014

If the status is "order" new date is 09/11/2014

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a few irregularities in your example: 1) your date field is actually a text field and 2) your math does not seem to be correct.  The following approach should work for you:

In the Pre-Logic Script Code

```
def correctDate(x,y):
  if x == "delivery":
    newValue = str(int(y.split("/")[0]) + 4)
    a = newValue + "/" +  y.split("/")[1] + "/" + y.split("/")[2]
    return a
  if x == "Order":
    newValue = str(int(y.split("/")[0]) - 5)
    b = newValue + "/" +  y.split("/")[1] + "/" + y.split("/")[2]
    return b
```

In the box below that:

```
correctDate(!state!, !current!)
```