# MapBasic subtract date columns

Tags: sql, mapinfo, mapbasic, date

Is it possible to create a MapBasic SQL command to subtract one date column from another and get the number of days between the two (positive or negative values)?

I have found the following process in FME and ArcGIS but need a MapBasic solution

https://knowledge.safe.com/questions/4349/subtract-dates.html and 
[Add or subtract days to date field using the field calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122013/add-or-subtract-days-to-date-field-using-the-field-calculator)

Comment: If they are actually just dates then you should be able to subtract them to get the difference in days without anything fancy. I suspect this won't work with Date/Time fields though.

Comment: Or, of course you could use the Day() Month() and Year() functions to pull out the relevant data and do the calculations based on those. Gets a bit messy with leap years, different days per month, etc... so probably easier to just use the straight up subtraction i mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Tom (@T_Bacon) wrote in the comments, this works nicely via the MapBasic window:

```
dim date1 as date
dim date2 as date
date1 = NumberToDate(20160912)
date2 = NumberToDate(20160913)
Print (date2 - date1) + " days"
```

The Message window will not say: "1 days"

So you can easily subtract two dates from each other.

Here's an example via SQL:

```
Select (ONEDATECOLUMN - ANOTHERDATECOLUMN) "DaysBetween"
   From SOMETABLE
```

Just make sure the columns are Date.

And here's an example where you subtract the date column from today:

```
Select (CurDate() - SOMEDATECOLUMN) "DaysBetween"
   From SOMETABLE
```

Comment: Thanks and rather than create a column with the current date can it be specified in the select statement? so you have Select ("Current date" - Other Date) ...where "Current date" is the command? to get the current date.

Comment: Sure, see the new example I just added